# Cannot see files in my external HDD

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, windows-8.1

I have HDD with a lot of video files. Usually I connect my HDD with TV to watch videos. Today I've connected the drive to my PC and noticed some hidden files, but nothing related to video. The files are:

- $RECYCLE.BIN
- System Volume Information (32KB)
- .mediaDB_3495978201.db (19KB)

In explorer I see that 159GB free of 596GB. How can I found hidden video files and recover it?

I have added screen with broken drive G.

[image]

Comment: Did your TV perform a firmware update? Maybe some programming with the TV caused this. Anyways you will need to set your folder options to `Show Hidden Files` if you want to see your videos.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus My TV has never been updated. Now I'm scanning drive with `Recuva` as @Dalton mentioned. It has been found something. I will let you know the results when it will be completed.

Comment: Can you right-click and go to properties of each file/folder and see which one is the biggest?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `Recuva` is still scanning. For files from screen `.cmdb` is the biggest, it's 32KB.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus `Recuva` has recovered a lot of files, but not all :(

Answer (score 1):

Open the hidden files it should show you all the files present (most probably the files will be present in RECYCLE.BIN folder). To recover deleted files you can use Recuva software http://www.piriform.com/recuva or any other recovery software.

Comment: If the files are really in the Recycle Bin, no need for extra software -- just open the Recycle Bin & select, then right-click and choose Restore.

Comment: Recycle Bin is empty. I've found files with a help of Recuva. Now, I'm trying to recover them.

Comment: I have recovered some files, but not all. I can see all files on my TV, but it is not accessible in PC. What's wrong?

Comment: Please Follow the below steps 1) goto run type diskmgmt.msc.. 2)Select your external hdd 3)how many partitions does it show? and what is the file system of each partitions? (should be NTFS)

Comment: @Dalton It's FAT32

Comment: try using activeboot software and browse your hardisk...http://www.lsoft.net/bootdisk.aspx

Comment: @Dalton What do you think if I convert disc file system to NTFS using cmd. Could it fix the problem? I don't want to lost the data.

Comment: You will lose your data....,btw did you try connecting your disk to some other computer? did you try activeboot? you can even use ubuntu OS(or any OS which can be booted using live cd) and then try opening your hard disk from that OS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are just hidden because of a virus or something like that.

You should try to unhide them:

1. Open a folder
2. Go to `Organize` > `Folder and Search Options`
3. Under `Folder Options` go to: `View`
4. Under `Hidden Files and Folders`, tick `Show hidden files, folders…`
5. Also Un-tick: `Hide protected operating system files`
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Click `Properties` in one folder, and at `General`, see if you can un-tick the `Hidden option`.

Comment: Still cannot see any files, I have added a screen shot, please review.