# External HDD is not accessible after using on TV

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, tv

I cannot see any files on my external hard drive after using on TV.
I have already posted details in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/670838/cannot-see-files-in-my-external-hdd) post. I can repair some files using recovery software, but I would like to know a reason of this behavior and I don't wish to recover all files every time after using TV. Please, help me.

Comment: VTC: Questions about TV's (aside from directly interfacing it with a computer) is off-topic for SU.

Comment: Sounds like your tv performed an operation the changed the file system check the manual for the tv for more information.  You don't tell us what TV you have so we can't tell you Exactly what happen

Comment: @Ramhound yes, it looks like tv changed the file system. My TV is Samsung UE22F5000AK